Two Activities are showing at a time when we click on turn on button in android
Hello in the below code if the device is in flight mode showing custom location popup and user press on turn button it is redirecting to location services screen.
But at a time two activites are opening one is redirecting to setting screen of the app and click on back button and then showing location services screen.
For refrence :
Turn ON -> Settings screen click on back button ->Location services screen
A.java:
    public void checkPermissionoffline(Activity activity, String value) {
            if (bleAdapter == null) {
                final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                bleAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
            }
            if (value != null && value.equals(String.valueOf(Constant.BLE_DISABLED))) {
                requestBluetoothEnable(activity);
            } else {
                if (!bleAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    bluetoothPermissionResult(Constant.BLE_DISABLED);
                } else {
                    if (bleAdapter != null && bleAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        if (!hasLocationPermissions(activity)) {
                            requestLocationPermission(activity);
                        } else {
                            if(isAirplaneModeOn(activity)) {
                            }
                            else
                               requestDeviceLocationSettings(activity);
                        }
                    } else {
                        requestBluetoothEnable(activity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        public boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Activity context) {
            if (Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                bluetoothPermissionResult(3);
  Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                context.finish();
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
    
            }
        }

